# Trying to draw an ellipse in a WPF window, but it is not visible

Tags: wpf, draw, drawingcontext, onrender, drawellipse

I am trying to create my own graph user control, I have one already working on win forms and I am trying to move it into WPF world.

I am starting with learning how to do drawing, so first thing I was trying to draw a black ellipse that fills an entire window, just to learn how coordinates works in WPF.

So here is the code, when I run the application, nothing is displayed, any idea what am I missing?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Black, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(Width / 2, Height / 2), Width / 2, Height / 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF is very different from WinForms. You do not have something like a Paint event handler where you constantly need to repaint invalidated areas.

The easist way to draw an ellipse that fills the whole window area in WPF is this XAML:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Fill="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

but of course there are a lot of other ways to achieve the same result.

If you need to do more complex things, WPF offers a large variety of classes that support graphics and multimedia. I'd suggest starting to read the [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744948%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) section of the online documentation on MSDN.

---

To come back to your specific problem, there are several things to mention.

First, you would have seen the result of your OnRender override if you had set the Window's `Background` property to `Transparent` and had drawn the ellipse in a color other than `Black`.

Then you would have realized that the drawn ellipse is larger than the window's client area. This is because the values of the `Width` and `Height` properties include the Window border. Even then, using the `Width` and `Height` properties for getting the actual width and height of a UI element in WPF is not the proper way, because these properties return `double.NaN` unless they were explicitly set (except in the Window class).

Instead, you would usually use the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties, as in this UserControl (which perhaps does exactly what you intended):

```
public partial class DrawingControl : UserControl
{
    public DrawingControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Black,
            new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1),
            new Point(ActualWidth / 2, ActualHeight / 2),
            ActualWidth / 2, ActualHeight / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete detailed answer

Comment: +1 Clemens, I have the same problem where specifying a background color other than `Transparent` obscures whatever I draw.  Is it possible to set the background color to anything else without blocking what's drawn?  Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu You mean you have an overridden OnRender method in your MainWindow? In short, you should simply not do that. If you *really need* to override OnRender, you should not do that in a Window, but in a custom control.

Comment: Clemens, I have a UserControl, and do my drawing within its OnRender method.  When I specify a Background color for my UserControl in XAML, the color blocks everything I draw.

Comment: I have an open question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229684/background-color-obstructs-wpf-usercontrol-content

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample i did,

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var canvas = new Canvas();
        Content = canvas;

        var element = new DrawingVisualElement();

        canvas.Children.Add(element);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += (s, e) =>
        {

            using (var dc = element.visual.RenderOpen())
                dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Black,
               new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 3),        // Border
               new Point(120, 120), 20, 40); 
        };

        Mouse.Capture(canvas);
        MouseDown += (s, e) => Mouse.Capture((UIElement)s);
        MouseMove += (s, e) => Title = e.GetPosition(canvas).ToString();
        MouseUp += (s, e) => Mouse.Capture(null);


    }
    class DrawingVisualElement : FrameworkElement
    {
        public DrawingVisual visual;

        public DrawingVisualElement() { visual = new DrawingVisual(); }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return 1; } }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visual; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks sajeetharan, but can you please explain what was missing from my original code?

Comment: You should add it inside a canvas

Comment: -1 For using the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event here. This is definitely unnecessary here and might lead OP into a completely wrong direction.

Comment: @Clemens Even i know that we can use Ecclipse and draw it, but i answered for his question!

Comment: In a very, very confusing way!