# Background color obstructs WPF UserControl content

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `UserControl`, which is referenced within XAML as follows:

```
<local:ColumnGraphRenderCtrl x:Name="graphCtrl" Grid.Column="1" 
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
```

The `UserControl` in question has several rectangle shapes, and they display fine.

**However**, if I specify a `Background` color, the specified color obstructs the rectangles, and nothing but the color is displayed. For example:

```
<local:ColumnGraphRenderCtrl x:Name="graphCtrl" Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1" 
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
```

(If I change the color to "Transparent", the rectangles do become visible.)

I also tried using a `ControlTemplate` for the `UserControl` (as part of a `Style`), but I got the same results (i.e. the background color blocking the content of the UserControl).

I looked up the *Control.Background* property on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which provides the following remarks:

> The Background property applies only to the resting state of a
>   control. The default style of the control specifies its appearance
>   when the state of the control changes. For example, if you set the
>   Background property on a Button, the button has that value only when
>   it is not pressed or disabled. If you want to create a control that
>   has a more advanced customization of the background, you must define
>   the control's style.
>
> This property only affects a control whose template uses the
>   Background property as a parameter. On other controls, this property
>   has no impact.

What is the significance of the remarks in MSDN, and how can I specify a background color without it blocking control content?

EDIT: The content control (the rectangles) are added manually in the codebehind, if that makes a difference.

UserControl code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace GraphingWithShapes
{
    public partial class ColumnGraphRenderCtrl: UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<NameValuePair> _dataPoints = null;
        private List<Color> _columnColors = new List<Color>() { Colors.Blue, Colors.Red, Colors.Green };

        public ColumnGraphRenderCtrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetData(ObservableCollection<NameValuePair> data)
        {
            _dataPoints = data;
            _dataPoints.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_dataPoints_CollectionChanged);
            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        void _dataPoints_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        public double GetLargestValue()
        {
            double value = 0;

            foreach (NameValuePair nvp in _dataPoints)
            {
                value = Math.Max(value, nvp.Value);
            }

            return value;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            if (_dataPoints != null)
            {
                double spaceToUseY = ActualHeight * 0.8;
                double spaceToUseX = ActualWidth * 0.8;
                double barWidth = spaceToUseX / _dataPoints.Count;
                double largestValue = GetLargestValue();
                double unitHeight = spaceToUseY / largestValue;

                double bottom = ActualHeight * 0.9;
                double left = ActualWidth * 0.1;

                Brush fillBrush;
                Pen outlinePen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
                int nIndex = 0;
                Rect rect;
                double height;

                foreach (NameValuePair nvp in _dataPoints)
                {
                    fillBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_columnColors[nIndex % _columnColors.Count]);

                    height = (nvp.Value * unitHeight);
                    rect = new Rect(left, bottom - height, barWidth, height);
                    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(fillBrush, outlinePen, rect);

                    left += rect.Width;
                    nIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `UserControl` code? I tried creating one myself as you described and I can't replicate the problem

Comment: yeah, I'm in the same boat. I've done this many times in a few of my projects, and the content is always visible because the Usercontrol's background is always on the bottom of it's children.

Comment: Just saw your edit. yes that could make a difference. If you are drawing to the UserControl. My suggestion is to put a canvas on your usercontrol and draw on those.

Comment: @TzahMama Added the code for the control.

Comment: Tried the following in the codebehind, but got the same result: `this.Background = Brushes.Blue;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to write a custom control that does its rendering by means of an overridden `OnRender` method you should not derive from `UserControl` or even `Control`, as they draw themselves via a `ControlTemplate`, which also fills their area with the `Background` brush. All that is done outside their OnRender method, so overriding it and not calling the base class' OnRender won't help.

Instead, derive from `FrameworkElement` or `UIElement`, declare a `Background` property and fill the control area with the background before doing the rest of the rendering:

```
public class CustomControl : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
        Control.BackgroundProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomControl));

    public Brush Background
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext); // just good practice
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Background, null, new Rect(RenderSize));

        // your rendering code goes here...
    }
}
```

You may find some more information in the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) article on MSDN. There is a section about deriving from FrameworkElement.

Comment: +1 WORKS! Thank you, both for the answer and for the education.  Since FrameworkElement does not support OnMouseDoubleClick(), I will find a workaround for it.  One additional question: Why is it OK to not call base.OnRender()?

Comment: The base implementation does nothing. However, it doesn't hurt to call it. It's good practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

So my solution to this works, but you'd have to fiddle with the width and height. In the usercontrol I addeda viewbox and a uniform grid.

```
<UserControl x:Class="GraphingWithShapes.ColumnGraphRenderCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Viewbox>
        <UniformGrid x:Name="GraphGrid" />
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Then I set it's width and height according to the data that comes in. Make the columns equal to the count of the data. (Note I didn't put in the logic to change graph color like you did). Then I added a Border (which has a border and a background) and add that to the unifrom grid. (code is here)

```
    public void SetData(ObservableCollection<NameValuePair> data)
    {
        _dataPoints = data;
        _dataPoints.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_dataPoints_CollectionChanged);
        GraphGrid.Columns = _dataPoints.Count;

        RebuildGraph();
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private void RebuildGraph()
    {
        GraphGrid.Children.Clear();
        GraphGrid.Height = GetLargestValue();
        GraphGrid.Width = _dataPoints.Count * 3;
        foreach (var item in _dataPoints)
        {
            AddGraphBar(item.Value);
        }
    }

    private void AddGraphBar(double value)
    {
        Border grid = new Border();
        grid.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
        grid.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        grid.Background = Brushes.Green;
        grid.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        grid.Height = value;
        GraphGrid.Children.Add(grid);
    }
```

and when I put a background color on my user control it works now. I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Thank you.  However, my code is using `DrawRectangle()` calls instead of shapes, so I cannot use your approach.

Comment: @Sabuncu ok so replace UniformGrid with Canvas, and draw on the canvas. You can't draw on the usercontrol because the background will write over what you are drawing on the usercontrol

Answer (score 1):

If you create a custom control using Visual Studio's template, it will create a Generic.xaml file that provides a ControlTemplate for the control.

The default settings in this template cause it to copy the Border's Background from the ControlTemplate, which causes the background (which is inexplicably rendered on top of your custom control) to over-draw your control.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

To resolve this, remove the `Border Background` from the ControlTemplate, and render a background-fill rectangle as the first thing you draw in your OnRender:

```
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Background, null, new Rect(RenderSize));
```